# scaling a subset of columns of data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to `scale` a subset of columns in my `data.table`. There are many of these that I would like to `scale` so i want to avoid specifying them all by name.  The columns that are not being scaled, I would just like to return as is.  Here is what I was hoping would work but it does not:

```
require(data.table)
x = data.table(id=1:10, a=sample(1:10,10), b=sample(1:10,10), c=sample(1:10,10))
> dput(x)
structure(list(id = 1:10, a = c(1L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 9L, 8L), b = c(4L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 2L), 
    c = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", 
"a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1a85d088>)

sx = x[,c(id, lapply(.SD, function(v) as.vector(scale(v)))), .SDcols = colnames(x)[2:4]]
   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'id' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sx = cbind(x[,-(2:4)],data.table(scale(x[,2:4])))
```

I suspect, it would be better for your workflow to melt your data.table to long format.

Comment: awesome, thanks! actually this is the end of the work process. the step after this runs a regression and that's the end of it.

Comment: This is the only solution I found that can handle a `by=` clause as well :). Amazing speed up from `ddply`.

Answer (score 9):

You could also assign by reference in a copy of the data table

```
sc <- names(x)[2:4]

sx <- copy(x)[ , (sc) := as.data.table(scale(.SD)), .SDcols = sc]
```

scale returns a matrix and iirc data.table doesn't like matrix columns.

Or,

```
sx <- copy(x)[ , (sc) := lapply(.SD,scale), .SDcols = sc]
```

[ The brackets around `(sc)` tell `data.table` to take the LHS value from the value of the variable in calling scope rather than the column name `sc` itself. ]

Comment: +1 I only recently discovered we don't even need `c()`, just `()` is enough.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I have used `{}` as well.

Comment: Neat. Will add some documentation somewhere about `()` and `{}` then to formalise it. Have also started to use it in `i` if subsetting by a logical column; e.g. `DT[(logicalCol)]`.